# invert a specific part of a list C#

Tags: c#, list, loops, panel

I need a program to reverse part of a list between two terminals.
Example :

List: 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4
Output: 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 (Only the 4 and 5 are inverted)

I found this:

```
                positionCrepe.Reverse(indexOfMaxToSearch, positionCrepe.Count);
```

But it doesn't work because I have a mistake:

> System.ArgumentException: The offset and length were out of bounds for this table or the number is greater than the number of index elements at the end of the source collection.

However

> indexOfMaxToSearch = 2

and

> positionCrepe.count = 5

and so it does not exceed the index of the table

Anyone have a solution? 
Thank you.

Comment: In that specific case you should just sort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument is *how many elements you want to reverse*, not how many elements there are in the list.

So if you want to reverse everything starting from `indexOfMaxToSearch`, you want to reverse `positionCrepe.Count - indexOfMaxToSearch` elements:

```
positionCrepe.Reverse(indexOfMaxToSearch, positionCrepe.Count - indexOfMaxToSearch);
```

The error message is actually saying that the first argument *plus* the second argument is out of range of the array.

Comment: I'm unable to find this overload of LINQ's reverse method. Is this actually `Array.Reverse`?

Comment: @JonathonChase No. It's [`List.Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Reverse_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: Are you here ? I got a question plz

Comment: @IzoDarkIzo You can post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the definition of Reverse,

index: The zero-based starting index of the range to reverse.
count: The number of elements in the range to reverse.

You can use the following to make it work. Count must be less then the remaining indecies

```
positionCrepe.Reverse(2, positionCrepe.Count - 2);
```